# Facebook OpenGraph GraphObject is returning empty object

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to read ratings from a Facebook page to display externally, using the PHP SDK. I already have a long live access token, and have been able to use it to pull in the main page data, but when I try access the `/ratings` endpoint, I just receive back an empty `Array ( )`

```
class FacebookReviews
{
    protected $session;
    protected $page;
    protected $ratings;
    protected $appId;
    protected $appSecret;

    function __construct($appId = null, $appSecret = null)
    {
        session_start();
        $this->appId = '123456789123456';
        $this->appSecret = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv';

        Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($this->appId, $this->appSecret);
        $this->session = new Facebook\FacebookSession('LONG LIVE ACCESS TOKEN I GENERATED ON THE GRAPH API');

        try {
          $this->session->validate();
        } catch (Facebook\FacebookRequestException $ex) {
          // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
          echo $ex->getMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
          // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
          echo $ex->getMessage();
        }

        try {
            $this->page = (new Facebook\FacebookRequest($this->session, 'GET', '/123456789123456/ratings'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        } catch(Facebook\FacebookRequestException $e) {
            echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
            echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function result()
    {
        return $this->page;
    }
}

$reviews = new FacebookReviews();

print_r($reviews->result());
```

If I remove `/ratings` from the request uri, it returns the data fine, but as I mentioned with it in there it doesn't work.

I generated the long live access token from my own account, which has admin access to the page

Comment: Have you tried using a page access token?

Comment: As far as I know that is what I'm using, a long live page access token. Unfortunately this is getting more complex, as this is for a page I am only temporarily the admin of, but I think this access token wont work once I am not admin

Comment: Debug the access token then to see if it is a page access token

Comment: Turns out it was for the wrong bloody page... Followed this step by step and it worked perfectly though
http://logicum.co/getting-a-facebook-page-permanent-access-token/

Comment: Interesting, the `page_id/ratings` endpoint returns an OAuthException when called with a user access token, but just an empty data array with a page access token that is not for the page in question – which explains why you had trouble spotting your mistake. @WizKid, you think this should be reported as a bug, or is that intended functionality?